# How to create a stub for relation models

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, loopback, loopback4

I have created hasManyThrough relation for 2 model
Like: this.repository.operations(id).create(operation);

I am able to create operation and relation for it. But when I am trying to write test cases for those methods having issues.

```js
repository.stubs.create.resolves('test');
```

can anyone help me to create a stub for

```js
this.repository.operations(id).create(operation);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of creating a stub, also I am using chai for assertions.

```
let sandbox;

    before(function () {
        chai.should();
        sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
        
    });

afterEach(function () {
        sandbox.restore();
    });


it('should get something', function () {
        let stub = sandbox.stub(object, ‘WhatYouAreStubbing’).returns(‘something’);

        let result = object.Method();

        stub.calledOnce.should.be.true;
        (result === undefined).should.be.false;
    });
```